# ITCSS - Onde ficam os arquivos de animações?

Tags: css3

Estou estudando ITCSS como uma maneira de estruturar melhor as minhas pastas e arquivos CSS - estou usando em conjunto com RSCSS.

À principio eu estava colocando as animações junto com os componentes ou objetos que seriam animados, mas pensei que a melhor forma seria separar eles em arquivos diferentes e salvar em uma pasta para serem reutilizados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe, se formos para o lado teórico da coisa acredito que o correto é colocar as animações em `Tools` (Ferramentas), vou explicar pq.

Uma vez que vc pode transformar um animação `@keyframes` em um `@mixin` e que de acordo com a documentação os `@mixins` devem ficar na pasta `Tools` o correto seria colocar as animações em `Tools`.

> **Tools**
>   É o lugar onde você vai guardar seus mixins e funções necessárias para a construção de seus layouts. Pode ser qualquer coisa, desde mixins de font-face, até mixins de **animações**, etc.

Fonte: https://willianjusten.com.br/organizando-seu-css-com-itcss/#tools

A ideia é que separando as animações em `toos` depois vc pode usa-las em qualquer elemento por exemplo. Veja que a classe é independente do elemento em si

```
<div class="animation-slide-in-up"></div>
```

Exemplo de `@mixin` com animação

```
@mixin keyframes( $animationName ) {
    @keyframes $animationName {
        @content;
    }
}

//Uso

@include keyframes( incrediblehulk ) {
    0% {
        color: #f8d2c0;
        // you can also use mixins inside this mixin!
        @include transform( scale(1) );
    }
    100% {
        color: #0f0;
        @include transform( scale(3) );
    }
}
```

E aqui tem link bem interessante de como criar uma biblioteca de animações

http://brandonbrule.github.io/scss-animation-keyframe-mixin/

Comment: Obrigado, Hugo! Entendi perfeitamente o uso =)

Comment: @FelipeOliveira sem problemas meu caro!